# developing facebook application, with out SSL (secure browsing)

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, facebook-apps

i am developing a facebook application for a while now, i have two applications. one in production with SSL. and the other for development and testing without SSL.
since facebook turn off the "secure browsing" control. all connection to facebook are now secured using HTTPS/SSL.

so now i cant develop again my application.

is there a way to tell the browser to just igone SSL for a specific web address ?

or do some other trick ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create self signed certificate and use that for your development server. You browser will warn you that it is self signed but you can ignore that warning.

Comment: great solution self signed certificat